# Office UI Fabric JS not on site anymore

Tags: office-ui-fabric

I went to Office UI Fabric's site today and noticed "Fabric.js" was removed as an option.

Is Microsoft discouraging it from being used?

Answer (score 2):

Last version update for Office Fabric JS ([office-ui-fabric-js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-js) package) happen 8 months ago and the latest commit was performed 3 months ago. In the same time [office-ui-fabric-react](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react) package is regularly updating and moving on full speed. Make up your own conclusion. By the way, FYI [Office UI Fabric JS](https://dev.office.com/fabric-js) has it's own website.

Answer (score 0):

Office UI Fabric JS is now officially dead. Fabric React and Fabric Core are the recommended libraries to use going forward.

We received this email from the Office 365 Message Center today:

> Do you have any internal line-of-business apps or add-ins that your
>   developers have made to look like Office? If so, they may be using a
>   library called Fabric JS. We want to inform you that we will no longer
>   be making updates to the Office UI Fabric JS, beginning October 1,
>   2019.
>
> Over the past few years, the team behind Office UI Fabric has been
>   working hard on Office UI Fabric React. It is a robust framework for
>   building experiences that fit seamlessly into a broad range of
>   Microsoft products. It includes many full-featured, production-ready
>   UI components, utilities for accessibility, styling, iconography,
>   toolkits, resources for designers, and more. Having reached this
>   milestone, we’re simplify our offering of UI frameworks. Going
>   forward, we recommend developers use Fabric React and Fabric Core to
>   build experiences that align with the Office user experience. As a
>   result, October 1, 2019 marks the official end of support for Office
>   UI Fabric JS. While we are no longer actively developing new features
>   or fixing bugs, all existing versions of Fabric JS will remain
>   available on Microsoft’s CDN and solutions built with Fabric JS will
>   continue to function normally.
>
> [How does this affect me?]
>
> If you have, or are building, applications that leverage Office UI
>   Fabric JS, you’re welcome to continue using it; however, Microsoft
>   will not fix any bugs and offers no guarantee that components will
>   stay current with latest Office user experience.
>
> [What do I need to do to prepare for this change?]
>
> If you have, or are building, applications that you would like to
>   ensure fit seamlessly into a broad range of Microsoft products,
>   instead of using Fabric JS, we recommend using Fabric React or Fabric
>   Core. To learn more about Fabric React and Fabric Core, please see the
>   Additional Information.